# Why nginx does not cache my JSON URL?

Tags: caching, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

JSON Url caching- Cache-Control:max-age=0, no-cache.
My configuration: ngnix.conf

```
location / {
             proxy_set_header Host $host:8092;
             proxy_pass http://172.16.1.121:8081/;
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
        }

location /app/index.php/market/mutualFund/Overview?bestPerformingajaxcall=1 {
            proxy_cache my_zone_2;
            proxy_buffering on;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 302 5m;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:8095;
            proxy_pass http://172.16.1.121:8081/app/index.php/market/mutualFund/Overview?bestPerformingajaxcall=1;
            proxy_read_timeout 300;
        }
```

Default

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 2000000;
    proxy_connect_timeout       200000000;
    proxy_send_timeout          200000000;
    proxy_read_timeout          200000000;
    send_timeout                200000000;

    proxy_cache_path /home/tejora/app/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_zone_2:8m max_size=50m;
    proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$is_args$args";
    proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m;
    proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;
```

}

I want to cache my JOSN url. no cache file into folder.

Comment: The `location` block as you currently have it will never match anything. See [how `nginx` processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration) specifically the part which states that it "test only a URI part of request line without arguments".

Comment: update question..